# How can I split my code into different files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login('');

client.on('ready', ready => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} is ready!`)
});
```

another.js

```
client.on('message', m => {
    if (m.content = '123') {
        m.delete()
    }
})
```

How i can make it work? I wanna split certain commands in others files.

Comment: Simply you can export client in index.js and import it from another.js

Check [this](https://javascript.info/import-export)

Comment: Checkout the [Discord.JS Event Handler Guide](https://discordjs.guide/event-handling/)

Answer (score 0):

Export `client` from `index.js` and import it in `another.js`:

```
// index.js
// the rest of the file, and...

module.exports = { client };
```

```
// another.js
const { client } = require('./index'); // or the correct path

// and the rest of the file
```